# how to read file csv without next()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wrote this code to read some rows from a csv formatted file, but it gives the error "StopIteration" and I think this is because it reached the end of the file...

The Python3 code is as follows:

```
    with open("trafficpcap.txt",newline = "") as filedns:
        readerpcap = csv.reader(filedns,delimiter = "\t")
        rowDns = []
        for count in readerpcap:
            rowDns = next(readerpcap)
            print("linea letta: ",rowDns)
            if(rowDns[0].find(ipdst) != -1):
                i = 0
                ipdns = ""
                rowd = rowDns[0]
                while i < len(rowDns[0]):
                    if(rowd[i] != ","):
                        ipdns = ipdns + rowd[i]
                        i = i + 1
                    else: break
```

Maybe something is wrong with the `for` loop?

This is a sample of the input file:

```
52.48.184.207,52.16.213.80  pnp.aptoide.com
216.58.198.33   lh4.ggpht.com
193.206.135.13  r2---sn-b5gg-ca9e.gvt1.com
34.246.212.92,34.240.116.214    webservices.aptwords.net
151.101.66.202,151.101.130.202,151.101.2.202,151.101.194.202    sdk.foursquare.com
31.13.90.2  graph.facebook.com
13.32.123.222,13.32.123.156,13.32.123.136,13.32.123.7   config2.mparticle.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never needed `next()` (unless you intentionally want to skip rows). The for loop is calling that for you

It's just

```
with open("file.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        # do row things
```

Ref [`csv.reader` usage](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Answer (score 0):

You can also omit any csv library, just simply open file and read (load to list / nested list):

```
#1
file_name = 'file_name.txt'
file_loaded = list()
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    file_loaded = file.readlines()

#2
file_name = 'file_name.txt'
delimeter=','
file_loaded = list()
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        file_loaded.append(line.split(delimeter))
```

Comment: Delimiter in your example may be empty sign: file_loaded.append(line.split( ))

Comment: Or `file_loaded = [line.rstrip() for line in open(file_name)]`... But the question actually wanted to process the CSV data rows, not just get lines